# What does it mean: "Cannot add entry to test result which is completed already"?

Tags: squish

I run Squish from command line by calling certain testcases of a testsuite with option `--testcase`. After each execution of a testcase I read this message on command line:

> [ERROR   ] Cannot add entry to test result which is completed already, type 7 with message 'Process exited.'

What does it mean? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@falkb, this usually means that Squish got the information that the or one of the AUTs (Application Under Test) has exited/quit while Squish had already closed the internal test report. Neither the fact that one of the AUTs exited nor that the message cannot be added to the report anymore seem relevant for your automation, and more recent versions of Squish should vastly reduce the number of cases where this occurs, so please consider trying again with a recent release or snapshot, and consider contacting the technical support of the vendor in case you are still unsure.